# WCF to iOS web method

Tags: ios, web-services, wcf, xamarin

I am developing an app on xamarin.ios. We have a WCF service that is not hosted by IIS. When I want to add this service as reference, Http 405 occurs.

[image]

But when I create a WCF service which is hosted by IIS, I can add it as Web Reference. On iOS project, there is not "Add Service Reference" as option, just "Add Web Reference".

So, As I understand, I need to convert WCF to some web ref.

Well, This WCF service is provided by a company, means, I cant change it. In this case, how to convert it as a web reference?

I have been looking for it since 1 week, but havent found out a solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

but basically I would use a REST endpoint to your service. It´s the easiest workaround and it´s the way Ive solved that in some apps. Then you can struggle in iOS with the connection and the parser. You can use AFNetworking for the connection and then parse the file using NSXMLParser or transform it in the endpoint to JSON, this is up to you.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but We cant change the service, its problem.. I think we have to add a converter? But I don't know what should I do for it?

Comment: Ey! in messaging orientated architecture, you build sometimes adapters or converters for different channels. It´s really common. You can have loads of services working in j2ee, .net, etc., with different technologies. You add an extra layer to abstract the low level model to be able to get a readable representation in upper layers in your architecture. Basically, sometimes it´s used an ESB to deal with that and build the SOA between the different parts. In your case, if you have just a service, you can decouple it by using a channel converter from the WCF service to JSON for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use WCF you can use the [Silverlight utility](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28359) to create the necessary proxy files.

I have sample in my GitHub repository that works for both iOS & Android. I never finished writing the Wiki to completion since WCF isn't the ideal transport for mobiles but if you need to use it then it should give you an example to work with.

https://github.com/sami1971/SimplyMobile/wiki/Step-by-step-WCF-client-creation-for-iOS-&-Android